# Python: Give me First n Rows where Value in Column A Is Equal to X, grouped by Category in Column C

Tags: python, string, loops, count, group-by

I have the following Python dataframe shown below:

[image]

I want to subset the data set so that: 
1. For each "Region", I am given the rows / Accounts which represent the first three "meetings" and first two "calls" from the "Activity" field

This is my desired dataset below:
[image]

I am currently using an inefficient workaround to get my desired data set.  Essentially, I created two new columns to sum up the number of meetings and calls at each row.  I then said give me the rows within each region where the sum of meetings is equal to three and the sum of the calls is equal to two.

Is there a better way to code this up?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your data in a database? Are the values in "Account" unique?

Comment: It's worth qualifying how *exactly* are you working on your dataset, "python" is too general for that. Is it a sql database? Pandas dataframe? Plaintext files read into a list of named tuples? something else? "created two new columns" would mean very different things in each of these scenarios.

Comment: It is a Python data frame

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to consider calls and meetings separately: group them by region, select the top 3 or 2, and concatenate the results. Assuming that your `data` is a pandas dataframe:

```
d1 = data[data['Activity'] == 'meeting'].groupby('Region')\
       .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Rank')[:3])
d2 = data[data['Activity'] == 'call'].groupby('Region')\
       .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Rank')[:2])    
pd.concat([d1, d2])
```

If the cut-offs were the same (say, 3 both for calls and meetings), you could walk away with a one-liner:

```
data.groupby(['Region', 'Activity'], as_index=False)\
             .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Rank')[:3])
```

Comment: yes, it is a dataframe; let me give this a try! thank you :)

Comment: Thank you!  What if the cutoffs were different by Region?  For example, 3 calls and 2 meetings for Region 1 versus 1 call and 1 meeting for Region 2?   How does the code change in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use case for pandas's `describe()` and `groupby()` functions.

I would walk through their tutorial as it is a bit difficult to explain in this format.
[One Pandas Tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/06%20-%20Lesson.ipynb)

Comment: This answer is not helpful. It is really just a comment.

Comment: thx for the quick response; looked at your link...not quite what I am looking for